# How to find the Merge Conflict Reason/Cause in Azure Repos - Branches - Pull Request

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos

I have two branches Master and FeatureB in Git Local Repositories.
Master branch contains 2 Files: FileA and FileB
FeatureB contains 1 File: FileB

Performed the Commands (`git add .`, `git commit -m "Changed FileB"`, `git push -u origin --all` from the FeatureB branch and then master branch).

While Creating a pull request from FeatureB Branch in Azure Repos, I'm getting merge conflict but unable to find the cause of that.

[image]

Could anyone assist me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There normally is 'Conflicts' tab next to 'Overview', 'Files', etc. Maybe are refresh will make it appear?

However with or without the 'Conflicts' tab you will have to merge `master` into `FeatureB` before the pull request can be completed. Merging `master` from `FeatureB` will reveal what the conflict is about or it will be resolved automatically during merge (but probably not since DevOps is complaining).

Solution:

1. Checkout `FeatureB`
2. Merge `master`:

   - fix the conflict
   - commit the merge
3. Push `FeatureB`